# App for Sony SmartWatch

Tags: java, android, wear-os

sorry for my english :(

I get this error when i build my project

```
01-21 00:27:27.305  20626-20626/ruben.wol.wareable E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ruben.wol.wareable, PID: 20626
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.requestApplyInsets
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onAttachedToWindow(WatchViewStub.java:119)
            at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12752)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2577)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2584)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2584)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1426)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6233)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

some people asks me for this file build.grandle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ruben.wol.wareable"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.87'
}
```

Comment: how are you running your build? Through Android Studio or the command line? Perhaps you are just using the wrong module.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you please explain what you are actually doing and then provide the exception and code.

Comment: I`m running the code on Android Studio, and I'm trying to create a WOL on my smartwatch. Dont have any exception, only crash and gives top error

Answer (score 1):

See the exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.requestApplyInsets
```

I think the version of the library containing `android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub`, does not have the method `requestApplyInsets`. Be sure you are using the correct version.

Example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Ok now I know what dont have method requestApplyInsets, what can I do to repair this? I didn't programmed this.