# No Such Method error in Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I implemented one Android wear application. It runs in emulator successfully but getting problem with android wear devices. I am getting below error:

> NoSuchMethodError: android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.requestApplyInsets

I am adding below dependency `com.google.android.support:wearable:1.2.0`.

I am not understanding whats the problem. If you have any idea about this issue please suggest me.

Comment: try with compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'

Comment: you can check this also...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057159/app-for-sony-smartwatch

Comment: 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0 also getting same error i want to run in api level 19

Comment: What API version is your Android Wear emulator?

Comment: You should not use wearable 1.1.0 since that library is old. Also, your comment about API 19 makes no sense because there was no Android Wear release for API 19. All Android Wear devices are always running on the latest API, so you don't need to support old API versions.

Comment: @WaynePiekarski thanks for your information i have the requirement to support the android 4.4.2 version.I am new to android wear applications i know the android wear is launched from 4.4w.2 means api level 20 but i am looking for supporting libraries which are supported to lower versions also

Comment: The API version used on the phone side does not have to be the same as used on the Android Wear side. For example, you can use Google Play Services on an API 10 phone, but embed an Android Wear APK that requires API 21. The Wear APK will only be used when the phone is paired with a wearable device, which will only happen from Android 4.3 an up.